# Анализ файла на функционал

Tags: ассемблер, reverse-engineering

Есть стартовая функция 
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

оно же в основном режиме:
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

В которой вызываетсья функция sub_410156(подсвеченно желтым). В данной функции мы можем увидеть следующие:
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

таже функция:
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

В строке

```
cmp     word ptr [esi], 'ZM'
```

(*третья строчка с начала функции*) происходит сравнение  содержимого по адресу esi с 'MZ'
 т.е происходит анализ PE файла(чуть ниже можно увидеть сравнение с 'PE').

Вопрос: не могу понять, откуда беруться данные файла?

Comment: Мой совет: основным режимом в IDA не используйте режим графов, переключайтесь на обычный режим с помощью пробела и в настройках сделайте чтобы автоматически не переключалось на режим графов. Второе: в функцию данные передаются через параметры - в данном случае либо через стек, либо через регистр ecx - см. в вызывающей функции `mov ecx, [ebp + ....]`. Точнее сказать можно будет, если добавите скриншот в дизассемблерном виде (а не в виде графа).

Comment: В режиме графов  переходы более наглядно показанны, потому  использую его. Меня интересует не механизм передачи параметров в функцию, а источник данных... непойму откуда появляються данные о файле который анализируеться.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Первая часть:

```
     push    ebp
     call    $+5
loc_410006:
     pop     ebp
```

Это типичный способ получения фактического адреса, по которому загружена программа. Выполняется `call` на следующую команду, при этом в стеке оказывается адрес этой самой команды. С помощью команды `pop ebp` этот адрес снимается со стека и кладется в регистр `ebp`.

```
mov     ebx, ebp
sub     ebp, offset loc_410006
```

Здесь программа вычисляет разницу (дельту) между фактическим адресом, по которому расположена программа, и адресом по которому предполагалось что она будет расположена. Дело в том, что при загрузке исполняемого файла в память загрузчик может расположить программу по базовому адресу не `0x400000`, а по любому другому (при условии наличия таблицы релокаций, которая в принципе может быть и пустой). По факту после `pop ebp` в регистре `ebp` может оказаться не `0x410006`, а например `0xC50006`, разница в этом случае будет равна `0x840000`. Обычно это круглое число (если смотреть на него 16-ричном представлении) с 3 нулями в конце, т.к. начальные адреса секций должны быть кратны 4096 (`0x1000`).

```
loc_41000F:
    mov     eax, 4096 ; 0x1000
    add     eax, 6 ; 0x1006
    sub     ebx, eax ; от фактического адреса метки loc_410006 вычитается число 0x1006, получается что-то вроде 0x40f000 + дельта
    mov     [ebp+410961h], ebx ; По фактическому адресу какой-то глобальной переменной записывается значение полученного выше адреса
    ; Это скорее всего та же переменная, которая внутри функции у вас называется varX
    mov     edx, offset aGetmodulehandl ; "GetModuleHandleA"
    add     edx, ebp ; Здесь опять же вычисляется фактический адрес строки "GetModuleHandleA"
    mov     ecx, [ebp+410C16h] ; В ecx кладется значение какой-то другой переменной (неинициализированной?)
    push    ebp ; значение дельты сохраняется на стеке
    call    sub_410156
    pop     ebp ; а потом восстанавливается
    cmp     eax, -1 ; проверяется значение, возвращенное функцией
    jz      short loc_41009C
```

В итоге перед вызовом функции в регистрах `ecx` и `edx` лежат значение какой-то переменной и адрес строки "GetModuleHandleA"

Подобный позиционно-независимый код может использоваться для того, чтобы включить его в состав другой программы без необходимости добавления записей в таблицу релокаций.

Теперь по поводу того, что расположено по адресу `0x40f000`. Как показал небольшой эксперимент, до первой секции располагается заголовок исполняемого файла. Собственно, вот экспериментальный код (компилируется с помощью flat assembler):

```
format PE GUI 4.0

include 'win32ax.inc'

.code

  start:
    xor eax, eax
    mov ax, [start - 0x1000]
    mov dword [buf], eax
    invoke MessageBox, HWND_DESKTOP, buf, "Title", MB_OK
    invoke ExitProcess,0

.data

buf rb 4

.end start
```

В месседж боксе выводится MZ, что и означает, что там находится начало заголовка файла. Откуда эти данные берутся - как я понимаю, сначала заголовок загружаются загрузчиком в память, дальше он разбирается, и после него догружаются секции файла. После загрузки секций заголовок файла остается в памяти.

Внутри функции `sub_410156` происходит проверка наличия сигнатур MZ и PE в заголовке (не понятно зачем, если файл таки успешно запущен), и похоже на проверку наличия импорта из библиотеки KERNEL32.DLL (по крайней мере в  тестовом экзешнике по смещению +128 от начала PE заголовка как раз находится массив структур Import Directory).

Для анализа того, что проверяет функция в заголовке исполняемого файла, можно при загрузке файла в IDA PRO поставить галку "Manual load", на все ответить да, тогда загрузится и заголовок файла, и, например, секция импорта в "сыром" виде, и оверлэй ("хвост" файла, не входящий ни в одну секцию), если он есть.

Answer (score 1):

Рискну предположить что call $+5, pop ebp получает адрес инструкции из start в регистре ebp, из которого потом вычитается RVA. В итоге, в ebp будет адрес загрузки модуля. Как верно было указано выше - графы зло. А вот отладчик - добро, он позволяет находить ответы на такие вопросы за пару минут.